# Asyncsocket error in ios 9 - Attempting to connect while connected or accepting connections. Disconnect first

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, asyncsocket

This code carry on some communication to server on app device. 
It worked fine until clients upgrade their iOS to version 9.

```
clientSocket = [[AsyncSocket alloc] initWithDelegate:self];

@try
{

    NSString *msg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ios:%@",encodeNum];
    if (!clientSocket.isConnected) {

        [clientSocket connectToHost:@"my.server.com" onPort:7009 error:nil];

    }

    NSData *data = [msg dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    [clientSocket writeData:data withTimeout:-1 tag:0];
}
@catch (NSException *exception)
{
    NSLog(@"exception: %@", exception);
}
```

In iOS 9, it throw following error:

```
 Attempting to connect while connected or accepting connections. Disconnect first.
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting the same issue. 
It seems `clientSocket.isConnected`can be false while it is still connecting. You need to listen to the delegate `didConnectToHost`to know when it has been connected.